# Any restrictions on pthread attributes creation?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, scheduling, timing

Following program is unable to assign the attributes in pthread. When I tried creating pthread_attr_setschedpolicy with other than SCHED_FIFO, then I'm unable to set the thread attributes successfully. Similar case with PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM scope.

What is wrong with current creation of thread?

How can I schedule the thread at particular time/event?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

void *process_ND(void *arg);
void *process_PFD(void *arg);
void *process_EICAS(void *arg);
void *process_IO(void *arg);

int main()
{
   pthread_t thread_PFD, thread_EICAS, thread_ND, thread_IO;
   pthread_attr_t attr_PFD, attr_EICAS, attr_ND, attr_IO;

   pthread_attr_init(&attr_PFD);
   pthread_attr_init(&attr_EICAS);
   pthread_attr_init(&attr_ND);
   pthread_attr_init(&attr_IO);

   if( (0 != pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr_PFD, SCHED_FIFO)) ||
       (0 != pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr_PFD, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED)) ||
       (0 != pthread_attr_setscope(&attr_PFD, PTHREAD_SCOPE_PROCESS)) )
   {
      printf("ERROR.... in setting the pthread Schedule, Policy, Scolpe attributes for PFD\n");//, error_num, strerror(error_num));
   }

   /* Set the EICAS thread attributes as desired */
   if( (0 != pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr_EICAS, SCHED_FIFO)) ||
       (0 != pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr_EICAS, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED)) ||
       (0 != pthread_attr_setscope(&attr_EICAS, PTHREAD_SCOPE_PROCESS)) )
   {
      printf("ERROR.... in setting the pthread Schedule, Policy, Scolpe attributes for EICAS\n");
   }

   /* Set the ND thread attributes as desired */
   if( (0 != pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr_ND, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED)) ||
       (0 != pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr_ND, SCHED_FIFO)) ||
       (0 != pthread_attr_setscope(&attr_ND, PTHREAD_SCOPE_PROCESS)) )
   {
      printf("ERROR.... in setting the pthread Schedule, Policy, Scolpe attributes for ND\n");
   }

   /* Set the IO thread attributes as desired */
   if( (0 != pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr_IO, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED)) ||
       (0 != pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr_IO, SCHED_FIFO)) ||
       (0 != pthread_attr_setscope(&attr_IO, PTHREAD_SCOPE_PROCESS)) )
   {
      printf("ERROR.... in setting the pthread Schedule, Policy, Scolpe attributes for IO\n");
   }

   //threadStatus_PFD = pthread_create(&thread_PFD, &attr_PFD, process_PFD, (void*)(pthread_array_param+0));
   threadStatus_IO = pthread_create(&thread_IO, &attr_IO, process_IO, (void*)NULL);
   threadStatus_PFD = pthread_create(&thread_PFD, &attr_PFD, process_PFD, (void*)NULL);
   threadStatus_ND = pthread_create(&thread_ND, &attr_ND, process_ND, (void*)NULL);
   threadStatus_EICAS = pthread_create(&thread_EICAS, &attr_EICAS, process_EICAS, (void*)NULL);
   printf("Created all the threads\n");
   return 0;
}

void *process_ND(void *arg)
{

}
void *process_PFD(void *arg)
{

}

void *process_EICAS(void *arg)
{

}

void *process_IO(void *arg)
{

}
```

Comment: Your process likely doesn't have permission to use those attributes.

Comment: BTW, I'm trying to run this in Cygwin environment and new to threading

Comment: Then the problem may be that the platform just doesn't support those attributes at all. Here's a tip though -- if you're new to threading, don't mess with priorities at all. They cause a lot more problems than they solve and you almost never need them. Instead, just code your threads to do the work you most want done.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz OK that helps, 2nd part of question: how about scheduling 1 at 5 ms and 2 at 15 ms etcetera? how can I program them to do this kind of scheduling.

Comment: Why is it that the first thing everyone tries to do with threads is to entirely defeat the point of threading? No, please, don't do that. Code your threads to only do the work you most want done so you don't have to care about how the scheduler runs your threads.

Comment: Also, don't `return` from `main` after creating your threads. That terminates your process!

Comment: Ok Thank You @DavidSchwartz